# How to make the keyboard appear directly in text field of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, focus, uitextfield, storyboard

Basically I want the same behavior that occurs when, on your iPhone, you go to Settings -> General -> About -> Name.

Notice that when you click on "Name", a new view appears prompting you to enter the name; and the text field is directly "selected" -- in other words, the keyboard directly pops up, without waiting for you to tap on the text field.

What I have now is a screen with a Table View that looks like this:

[image]

This screen is linked using the Storyboard segues to the rest of my interface. It works fine, but the text field doesn't directly get focus. I have to tap on it every time to make the keyboard appear.

How do I make the keyboard appear directly? Do I have to use code, or is there a way to do it in the Storyboard editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this using storyboard only, but the way to do it in code is fairly easy.  When your view loads, send a `becomeFirstResponder` message to your text field.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```